# Input/Output batching technique

Tags: performance

I was reading a paper and i saw a mention of the I/O batching technique to minimize the overhead of I/O. Curious, I tried to find resources to learn about this technique, but could't find nothing describing how it's done.

Does anybody know how it works? How this technique is implemented?

Thanks.